# is there a way to know first broker port for Kafka client ( producer or consumer) during sasl authentication

Tags: apache-kafka, sasl

I am trying to create Kafka producer and consumer with SASL authentication. During SASL authentication I would like to know about the specific broker and port that is selected for very first time from the list of brokers passed.
I only know hostname but not port number.

Comment: What is the specific problem you are trying to solve? Clients connect to _multiple brokers_, based on where partitions are hosted

Comment: So, I would like to change the broker servername based on port picked up during producer.send(). Since it is selected at last min, I dont know how to find which broker will be picked and where I can intercept to change the broker servername.

Answer (score 0):

> only know hostname but not port number

A port is required by bootstrap-server config, so I'm not sure I understand this...

> the specific broker and port that is selected for very first time from the list of brokers passed

The one that is selected shouldn't matter. All brokers can respond to the same request, and all broker info will be returned to the client before the producer starts. You can use `AdminClient.describeCluster` for cluster information.

But sounds to me like you need to talk to the kafka admin who configured `advertised.listeners`.

You can also use `kcat -L`  option to find this information remotely.

> would like to change the broker servername based on port picked up during producer.send()

You **cannot** modify data in a Producer batch. The advertised listeners are what will be used by the network protocol.

You'd need to implement a proxy that would redirect the data somewhere else or intercept the Kafka TCP packets and rewrite them to do anything else.

---

In Java, to find the exact server a particular record would be sent, you'd need to use the `DefaultPartitioner` class to find the partition each record would be sent to, using its key. This assumes your records have non null keys.
Then you need to `describeTopics` using an `AdminClient` instance. The result of describing a topic returns a list of TopicPartitionInfo. Filter this by the partition gotten for the record.
These have a leader() method that returns a Node object, which has host and port information. The leader partition is where the data will be sent when the producer buffer is flushed.

https://kafka.apache.org/31/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/Node.html

For a consumer, look at its partition assignment, then do the same.

Comment: thank you for the details! Let me try the proxy method and see.

Comment: For example, you could write a REST application that accepts HTTP requests and wraps a Producer but at startup, it could cache Kafka cluster details

Comment: I was trying to put load balance in front to it for redirection but looks like I need custom option

Comment: TCP load balancers will not work with Kafka. Client must communicate directly to individual leader brokers.